# hyperlink image in magento

Tags: magento, hyperlink

I am fairly new to coding and magento back end, so please accept my apologies if I am asking something extremely obvious. i am trying to associate a hyperlink to an image in magento, which is in the middle bit of the page (not header, not footer...?  i accessed those /app/design/frontend/default/XXXXXX/template/page/html/header.phtml and the rest, but no luck with where I should put the code in the front page  I can not find the file I should go into in order to hyperlink the image  many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of the cases of magento front page these pages are cms pages. You can go to admin->CMS->Pages and look for home or home page under url key. Click on it to modify and in content section choose the page where you want to edit.

if your home page has code to display data through template(.phtml) than look for that file and add your code to display image.

Comment: Many thanks Ram Sharma for your help. it did not have any reference to a phtml, however had some code in there which is what I think I was looking for. Hopefully I will manage from here. All the best

Comment: Ram it was actually in this form: <div class="promo-bottom"><a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/media/promo4.jpg'}}" alt="Promotion 4" /></a></div>. I just changed the # with the hyperlink path and worked!. I noticed that it was more <div class="">, which I do not know either where I could locate those, if I should need to amend something else. Sorry to be a pain, any ideas? thanks, your help is being much appreciated!